# C# Selenium, can't find any elements after logging in

Tags: c#, selenium

I use Selenium with ChromeDriver. When I open up a driver and manually go to a webpage, and then start running my code, everything works fine. However, if I log in to the website and manually go to the same page as before (it's the exact same page but logged in), I won't even find the html element:

```
var el = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("html"));
```

returns

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:........../elements timed out after 60 seconds.
```

The assignment

```
var el = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*"));
```

returns the same thing, there's literally nothing. Shouldn't I at least get a "cannot find element" exception?

Now if I log out it works again (everything is done in the same instance of ChromeDriver)

Comment: Can you share the code you are using that reproduces the issue? And, more importantly, can you share the HTML to the page you are automating, and, quite possibly, a link to the page? You will get a `NoSuchElementException` if the element located on the page does not exist. Seems like there may be an `iframe` element on page scenario where you are logged in, but I can't help much more than this without seeing the page.

Comment: Should not driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*")); find the iframe element? I have also tried driver.FindElements(By.TagName("*"));

Comment: I can’t really answer those questions without seeing HTML from the page. But I don’t think calling with an empty selector will find anything at all.